# PHP Server-Sent Events: trigger custom event from another file

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I need to notify the client(s) whether some of the clients made changes on the database. I consider it to be a single-directional connection (it's only the server who sends events), so I do not need WebSockets.

The logic is as follows:

- Client fetches the common API (let's say `/api.php?action=add&payload=...`), and with this fetch the change on DB is being made.
- After `mysqli_result` returned true, the server-sent event should be triggered to notify other clients (or their service-workers) about DB changed.

The caveats are:

- My SSE logic is placed on a separate file (`/sse.php`) to not make a mess in API logic and to listen to separate endpoint clientside. So I need to trigger SSE from `api.php` and push the result from there to all clients.
- In `sse.php` I defined a function for pushing which takes the message from `api.php` as a param. Whatever I've tried, this function was never called.
- **I strongly want to avoid making daemons and any kind of infinite loops**. But without them, the connection for the clientside listener (`eventSource`) closes and reopens every 3 seconds.

The current state of this all:

`api.php`

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include 'connection.php';       // mysqli credentials and connection object
include_once 'functions.php';   // logics

$action = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : 'fail';
switch ($action) {
    case "add":
        $result = api__handle_add(); // adds data to DB and returns stringified success/failure result
        require "./sse.php";         // file with SSE logic with ev__ namespace
        ev__send_data($result);      // this defined function should send message to clients
        break;
    // ...
    case "testquery":
        require "./sse.php";
        ev__send_data("Test event!!! Ololo");
        break;
    case "fail": default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden', true, 403);
}
```

`sse.php`

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Connection: keep-alive");

$_fired = false;   // flag checking for is anything happening right now

while (1) {        // the infinite loop I strongly want to get rid of
    if (!$_fired) {
        usleep(5000);  // nothing to send if nothing is fired, but I should keep the connection alive somehow
    }  else {
        // here I should call 'ev__send_data($message_from_api_php)'
        // thus I require this file to `api.php` and try to call 'ev__send_data' from there.
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

function ev__send_data(string $msg) {
    global $_fired;
    $_fired = true;
    echo "data: $msg". PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(1000);
    $_fired = false;
}
```

The clientside implementation is typical, with `onopen`, `onerror` and `onmessage` handlers of `eventSource`. I think I don't need to take it here as it has no differences from thousands of examples I've seen here on SO and at other sources.

To conclude: I want to trigger SSE's from outside SSE-file and pass pieces of data from outside, and I want to get rid of `while (1) {}` and emit events only when something really happens. I've come across thousands of tutorials and SO topics, and found nothing but typical "tutorial cases" about how to send server time to the client every n seconds and stuff. And I think I don't need WebSockets (considering that my local dev environment is Win10 + XAMPP, my prod environment will be something Linux-like and I don't think I can implement my own WebSocket without third-party dependencies which I don't want to install).

Do I have any chance?

**EDIT**

I found a little different approach. Now my server event generation depends on boolean flags that were settled in MySQL database in separate `flags` table. When I need an event to be emitted, API changes definite flag (for the very this example, when one client had submitted some changes in DB, API also makes the query to `flags` table and sets flag `DB_CHANGED` to `1`). And `sse.php` makes query to `flags` table each iteration of the infinite loop (every 5 seconds) and emits events depending on the flags' state, and after emitting, sets the corresponding flag to `0` via one more query. This kinda works.

Example of current `sse.php`:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

require_once "connection.php";  // mysqli connection object
set_time_limit(600);

stream();

function stream() {
    global $connection;

    while (1) {          // oh that infinite loop
        $flags = [];     // there will be fetched flags from DB
        $flags_sqli = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `flags`");
        while ($flag = $flags_sqli->fetch_assoc()) {
            $flags[$flag['key_']] = ev__h__to_bool_or_string($flag['value_']);
        }

        if ($flags['ON_TEST']) {
            ev__send_data("Test event!!! Ololo");
            ev__update_flag("ON_TEST", "0");
        } elseif ($flags['ON_DB_ADD']) {
            ev__handle_add();
        } else {
            echo PHP_EOL;      // keep connection alive - push single "end of line"
        }

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(5);    // interval per iteration - 5 secs
    }
}

function ev__send_data(string $msg) : void {
    echo "data: ".date("d-m-Y")." ".date("H:i:s").PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: $msg".PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

function ev__handle_add() : void {
    global $connection;
    $table = $connection->query('SELECT `value_` FROM `flags` WHERE `key_` = "LAST_ADDED_TABLE"')->fetch_row()[0];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `banners_".$table."` WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `banners_".$table."`)";
    $row = $connection->query($query)->fetch_assoc();

    echo "event: db_add_row".PHP_EOL;
    echo 'data: { "manager": '.$row['manager_id'].', "banner_name": "'.$row['name'].'", "time": "'.date("d-m-Y").' '.date("H:i:s").'" }'.PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

    ev__update_flag("ON_DB_ADD", "0");
}

function ev__update_flag(string $key, string $value) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "UPDATE `flags` SET `value_` = '$value' WHERE `flags`.`key_` = '$key';";
    $connection->query($query);
}

function ev__h__to_bool_or_string($value) {
    return $value === "0" || $value === "1"
        ? boolval(intval($value))
        : $value;
}
```

Therefore, I didn't get rid of the infinite loop. Considering that there will be a very few concurrent connections (max 3-5 sessions per one time) (when in prod), this very case should not make performance troubles. But what if it would be some kind of hard-loaded service? As an answer, I want to see optimization tips for the case of `Server-Sent Events`.